# Perl help dereferencing a reference to an array of hash references, containing record set data

Tags: perl, amazon-route53

I'm using the a Amazon Perl module that returns a reference to an array of hash references as $record_sets, containing record set data and I'm having a hard time dereferencing it. I can print the data using data dumper but I need to be able to manipulate the data. Below is the documentation provided for the module

Thanks In Advance:

```
#list_resource_record_sets
#Lists resource record sets for a hosted zone.
#Called in scalar context:

$record_sets = $r53->list_resource_record_sets(zone_id => '123ZONEID');

#Returns: A reference to an array of hash references, containing record set data. Example:

$record_sets = [
{
name => 'example.com.',
type => 'MX'
ttl => 86400,
records => [
'10 mail.example.com'
]
},
{
name => 'example.com.',
type => 'NS',
ttl => 172800,
records => [
'ns-001.awsdns-01.net.',
'ns-002.awsdns-02.net.',
'ns-003.awsdns-03.net.',
'ns-004.awsdns-04.net.'
]
```

Comment: Note that there is a comma missing after the `type => 'MX'`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you have a array-reference, e.g. $x = ['a','b','c'], you can dereference it two ways.

```
print $x->[0]; # prints a
print $x->[1]; # prints b
print $x->[2]; # prints c

@y = @{$x}; # convert the array-ref to an array (copies the underlying array)
print $y[0]; # prints a
print $y[1]; # prints b
print $y[2]; # prints c
```

A hash-ref works the same, except it uses curly braces.  E.g. $x = {a => 1, b => 2, c => 3}.

```
print $x->{a}; # prints 1
print $x->{b}; # prints 2
print $x->{c}; # prints 3

%y = %{$x}; # convert the hash-ref to a hash (copies the underlying hash)
print $y{a}; # prints 1
print $y{b}; # prints 2
print $y{c}; # prints 3
```

Applying this to your example, which has nested structures you can do this.

```
for my $x ( @{$record_sets} ) {
  print $x->{name}, "\n";
  print $x->{type}, "\n";

  for my $y ( @{$x->{records}} ) {
    print $y, "\n";
  }
}

# or something more direct
print $record_sets->[0]->{name}, "\n";
print $record_sets->[0]->{records}->[1], "\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

$record_sets is an array reference. To dereference it, you can use

```
my @array = @{ $record_sets };
```

Each record set is a hash reference.

```
for my $record_set ( @{ $record_sets } ) {
    my $set = %{ $record_set };
}
```

For example, to get the names and records (array ref):

```
for my $record_set ( @{ $record_sets } ) {
    print $record_set->{name},
          ': ',
          join ', ', @{ $record_set->{records} };
    print "\n";
}
```